# How to make one key combination (e.g Ctrl+tab) shortcut for changing focus between two columns in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want `Ctrl+Tab` to switch between two columns.

```
If (Column 1 is on focused) and (Ctrl+tab is pressed){
    focus to Column 2
else
    focus to column 1
```

I want the proper syntax for sublime text. I am learning python so I have a python file in one column and a python interpreter (through the Sublime-Repl plugin) in the other column. Using the default `Ctrl+1` and `Ctrl+2` shortcuts seem very tedious so i want `Ctrl+Tab` to do the job.

Here is the link to picture! (i cant display it here because i am new)
http://www.flickr.com/photos/sadukgena/12207602826/

Comment: what do you mean by columns? Are you talking about different view panes, like a split panel? Posting an image showing your desired behavior would be very helpful.

Comment: View->Layout->Columns:2 in Sublime text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if there is a built in command to alternate, but it's straight forward with a plugin. Note that if you do not have 2 groups, nothing will happen.

```
import sublime_plugin


class PaneSwitch(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        window = self.window
        if window.num_groups() != 2:
            return
        active_group = window.active_group()
        if active_group == 0:
            window.focus_group(1)
        else:
            window.focus_group(0)
```

Create a plugin with the above content. The command you will bind to is `pane_switch`.